Exception at mappermock.verify
Below is my service method
public async Task<ServiceResponse<AnnotationMasterResponse>> CreateAnnotation(AnnotationMasterRequest annotationMasterRequest)
{
    return await serviceResponseExceptionHandler.HandleAsync(async () =>
    {
        var annotationMaster = _mapper.Map<AnnotationMaster>(annotationMasterRequest);
        annotationMaster.AnnotationMasterId = Guid.NewGuid();

        var responseResult = await base.Insert(annotationMaster);
        return responseResult.DataResult;
    }, annotationMasterRequest);
}

Test Case for above method
[Fact]
   public async Task CreateAnnotation_Success()
   {
       // Arrange
       var annotationRequest = new AnnotationMasterRequest
       {
           AnnotationMasterName = "test"
       };

       var annotationMaster = new AnnotationMaster
       {
           AnnotationMasterName = annotationRequest.AnnotationMasterName,
       };

       var annotationResponse = new AnnotationMasterResponse { };

       var expectedResponse = new ServiceResponse<AnnotationMasterResponse>
       {
           Success = true,
           HttpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
           DataResult = annotationResponse
       };
  
       _mapperMock.Setup(m => m.Map<AnnotationMaster>(It.IsAny<AnnotationMasterRequest>()))
.Callback<object>(req => Console.WriteLine($"Mapper called with: {req}"))
.Returns(annotationMaster);


       _baseRepositoryMock.Setup(repo => repo.Insert(It.IsAny<AnnotationMaster>())).ReturnsAsync(true); // or false, depending on the test

       _exceptionHandlerMock.Setup(h => h.HandleAsync(It.IsAny<Func<Task<AnnotationMasterResponse>>>(), annotationRequest)).ReturnsAsync(expectedResponse);

       var result = await _annotationMasterService.CreateAnnotation(annotationRequest);

       // Assert
       Assert.NotNull(result);
       Assert.True(result.Success);
       Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, result.HttpStatusCode);
       Assert.NotNull(result.DataResult);

       _mapperMock.Verify(m => m.Map<AnnotationMaster>(It.Is<AnnotationMasterRequest>(req => req.AnnotationMasterName == annotationRequest.AnnotationMasterName)), Times.Once);
   }

Getting error at _mapperMock.Verify
Moq.MockException: '
Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: m => m.Map(It.Is(req => req.AnnotationMasterName == annotationRequest.AnnotationMasterName))
